# How to scan a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly to create the intellisense XML?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, xml-documentation

We have a C++/CLI mixed mode assembly out of which we produce an XML file that we use for both, Sandcastle documentation and Intellisense.

We use a tool which scans the assembly and create all  entries for us, unfortunately I don't know how this tool works and it is unable to handle method signatures like:

```
void foo([Out] long bar);
```

The XML file is expected this parameter to be System.Int32!CompilerServices.IsLong@ but our tool just can't handle that.

In other words, how do you scan an assembly to create the XML file needed for Intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you can do this yourself, then you can load it up using the Metadata API  ([link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404384.aspx)) and output the meta data any way you like. The API is a bit exotic and takes some getting used to, but it will get you there.